# Codeigniter URL issues in routes.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-hmvc

In my application fornt end is MVC and backend HMVC.
I have an issue in backend urls.I define all my front end urls in routes.php.(not backend)

like this

```
$route['(.+)/(.+)/(.+)'] = "homes/abc/$1";
```

But this affect my backend working(case 3 parameter passing)

Any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Try adding route for admin url before

```
$route['(.+)/(.+)/(.+)'] = "homes/abc/$1";
```

like

```
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/index/$1';
$route['(.+)/(.+)/(.+)'] = "homes/abc/$1";
```

or if you want to do some hack then:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'admin/') === false){
  $route['(.+)/(.+)/(.+)'] = "homes/abc/$1";
}
```